# Multiple mouses connected to computer, how to determine the exact mouse that triggered the event in Applet?

Tags: java, applet, awt, mouseevent, mouselistener

I am planning to code a buzzer for a event. There will be multiple teams and each team will have a mouse to click when they know the answer, now I have to determine the mouse that clicked first. All the mouses are connected to the same computer. Is it possible to identify the mouse that triggered the event?

Comment: I guess that would be very low level. Have you considered checking which mouse button was pressed (player1 = left click, player2 = right click)?

Comment: Give each team their own buzzer.

Comment: Is it possible to have different cursors for each mouse connected to a computer? Any software to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Native methods are the only way to do this, and I don't think native methods could help you unless you hack the operating system. The operating system hides all distinction between two mouses. You could also rewire the mouses so that one person can only right click and one person can only left click, and distinguish between right and left clicks.